# Как обновить столбец CLOB содержащий XML?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, clob

Столкнулась с необходимостью обновить столбец таблицы с типом CLOB, содержащий XML информацию с тэгами. Конкректно тэги в которых будет лежать информация не известны, например, мне нужно обновить телефон клиента.

Вопрос как сделать это наиболее эффективно. На текущий момент сделала реализацию обновления следующим образом :

1. завела переменную для входных данных типа `varchar(4000);`
2. считываю данные и записываю их в переменную:

   ```
   select dbms_lob.substr(t.request, dbms_lob.getlength(t.request),1) as request 
   into variable 
   from logfiles t
   ```
3. а дальше уже используя регулярные выражения ищу информацию с маской содержащий телефон `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`
4. полученные данные передаю в `CLOB`, т.е. его обновляю

Метод рабочий, но каждый раз `CLOB` записывать в переменную, учитывая миллионы (как минимум) будет слишком затратно по ресурсам и долго. А выдержит ли БД такие нагрузки далеко не понятно, т.к. информации о технических сведениях вовсе нет.

Принимаются дельные советы и ссылки на статьи.

Comment: Дельный совет, напишите минимальный воспроизводимый пример того, что вы сделали, и дайте пример входных данных. Пока не совсем понятна ваша задача.

Comment: В колонке с типом CLOB XML документы обычно только хранятся, для обработки они в таком виде плохо подходят. Обычно их преобразовывают в более удобный тип данных xmlType. Почему вы решили редактировать документы непосредственно как текст? На эти документы действительно нет никаких схем?

Answer (score 2):

Если заранее известно, что и чем заменять, то стандартные функции по поиску и замене текста также реаботают для `CLOB`. Обычное обновление значения столбца будет достаточно:

```
create table t (id, doc) as
    select 1, to_clob ('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<contacts>
  <contact>
    <name>Ivan Ivanov</name>
    <phone>123-456-7890</phone>
  </contact>
  <contact>
    <name>Vasya Pupkin</name>
    <mobile>+7(923)-456-7891</mobile>
  </contact>
</contacts>') from dual;

update t set
    doc = replace (doc, '+7(923)-456-7891', '+7(925)-456-7892')
where instr (doc, '+7(923)-456-7891')>0;

1 row updated.
```

---

В противном случае, следует проанализировать, в каких узлах какие значения хранятся, чтобы на основе этого решить, эффективней ли будет обновлять документ как текст или стоит его обрабатывать другими инструментами, например XQuery.

Пример запроса для анлиза структуры XML документа:

```
select id, nodePath, nodeValue 
from t, xmlTable ('              
    for $i in $doc/descendant-or-self::*
        return 
            <element>
                <elpath> {$i/string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/name(.), ''/'')} </elpath>
                <eltext> {$i/text()}</eltext>
            </element>' passing  xmlType (doc) as "doc" columns 
    nodePath  varchar2(100) path '//elpath',
    nodeValue varchar2(100) path '//eltext' )
/
        ID NODEPATH                         NODEVALUE       
---------- -------------------------------- ----------------
         1 contacts                                         
         1 contacts/contact                                 
         1 contacts/contact/name            Ivan Ivanov     
         1 contacts/contact/phone           123-456-7890    
         1 contacts/contact                                 
         1 contacts/contact/name            Vasya Pupkin    
         1 contacts/contact/mobile          +7(925)-456-7892
```